# When MUST we use noun phrase + adjective , not adjective + noun?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, prepositional-phrases, noun-phrases

I always catch my students using adj + noun even when it's not suitable but I don't know how to explain **why** we can't always do that and what the **rule** is.

For example:

> *Mental health issue people* need access to healthcare (wrong)
>
> *People with mental health issues* need access to healthcare (correct)

What's the grammar rule here?

Comment: What type of **health** are we talking about: physical or mental? Noun adjunct: *Mental health* What are we discussing: people who have **problems** (issues) about their mental health or the different **disorders** of mental health? Noun adjunct: *mental health problems/issues* OR *mental health disorders*

Comment: It's not so much a "grammar rule" as a "usage rule". A "mental health issue person" suggests that you are *defining a person's identity* as "a person with mental health issues", in the same way you would perhaps say "No thanks, I'm a coffee person" when asked if you want tea. As such, "mental health issue people" may not be *incorrect*, so much as *offensive*.

Comment: @PrimeMover I don't think there's a way to read *\*mental health issue people* as anything grammatical - a person who *is* a mental health issue? A person who deals with mental health issues, maybe (as in, a very Buffy-speak way to say "psychiatrist")? But definitely not as "a person who has mental health issues" - I'm fairly sure noun adjuncts never indicate possessive relationships.

Comment: @PrimeMover I agree with Maciej... One could say "Mentally ill people" and the sentence is now grammatically correct, though still just as offensive. The question is: Why is "Mentally ill people" grammatically correct and "Metal health issue people" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @MaciejStachowski English is remarkably more flexible than that.

Comment: To me, ***mental health people*** would *always* mean ***healthcare professionals*** (who work in that specific area of healthcare). It wouldn't be particularly idiomatic to shoehorn the attributive noun ***issue*** in there, but personally I'd normally understand that as being a reference to people who address "social issues" in the field of mental health care (Should we treat temporary workers from overseas? Should employers have to offer sufferers extra support? Should mentally impaired people be allowed to vote?). It's not "grammatically incorrect" - just clumsy, and to be avoided.